# Aweber API - /subscribers endpoint not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, aweber

I have a problem reaching the /subscribers endpoint of the Aweber API, when I try to use it, I get this as a result: [image]

which usually speaks for itself and it means the access token is ivalid or expired, but when I try to access the /accounts endpoint of the api with the same token, the request goes through:
[image]

Both requests are using the same header which uses Bearer ${Access token}:
[image]

just for more info, this is the error code from /subscribers call:
[image]

I also added all possible scopes for the auth:
[image]

Comment: Having this same issue with AWeber api, /accounts and /lists endpoints work but /subscribers always returns 401 unauthorized.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that your app is requesting and has the correct authentication Scopes to get access to the subscribers endpoint.

Specifically:

> `subscriber.read` -
> Retrieve subscribers and their activity
> Required for the following endpoints: get subscribers, get subscriber, get > subscriber activity, get subscribers for message, find subscribers for > account, find subscribers for list

See the api docs about different security scopes at https://api.aweber.com/#tag/Authentication-Overview